# Column Maniputation

Tags: etl

I would like to group my rows of inputs according to the first string of many comma-separated.
Basically, there will be 3 groups, which are "Motifs", "Chromatin_Structure" and "Protein_Binding"
The important output is the third one after 2 "|".
There might be some duplicates too like K562. The duplicates are not needed.
If the strings are not present, simply put a ". (dot)"

Input:

```
Motifs|PWM|Sox17|,Motifs|PWM|Sox8|,Chromatin_Structure|DNase-seq|K562|Znf4g7d3,Chromatin_Structure|DNase-seq|K562|,Chromatin_Structure|DNase-seq|TCF7L2|Znfe103c6,Protein_Binding|ChIP-seq|CTCF|HeLa-S3|,Protein_Binding|ChIP-seq|CTCF|HeLa-S3|
.
Motifs|PWM|TCF11|
Protein_Binding|ChIP-seq|MAFF|HepG2|
```

Desired output:

```
Sox17,Sox8  K562,TCF7L2 CTCF
.   .   .
TCF11   .   .
.   .   MAFF
```

Codes that I tried.

```
sed 's/Motifs|PWM|//'
```

Appreciate your helps!

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) Even though you added a code sample, I don't see how that would attempt to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl one-liner (Using the term loosely):

```
$ perl -F, -lane '
my (%groups, @output);
for my $grp (@F) {
    my @x = split /\|/, $grp;
    $groups{$x[0]}{$x[2]} = 1;
}
for my $n (qw/Motifs Chromatin_Structure Protein_Binding/) {
    if (exists $groups{$n}) {
        push @output, join(",", sort keys %{$groups{$n}});
    } else {
        push @output, ".";
    }
}
print join("\t", @output);' input.csv
Sox17,Sox8  K562,TCF7L2 CTCF    
.   .   .   
TCF11   .   .   
.   .   MAFF
```

And because I think it's woefully underappreciated as a scripting language, a `tcl` version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

proc main {} {
    while {[gets stdin line] >= 0} {
        foreach grp [split $line ,] {
            set x [split $grp |]
            dict set groups [lindex $x 0] [lindex $x 2] 1
        }
        foreach n {Motifs Chromatin_Structure Protein_Binding} {
            if {[dict exists $groups $n]} {
                lappend output [join [dict keys [dict get $groups $n]] ,]
            } else {
                lappend output .
            }
        }
        puts [join $output \t]
        unset groups output
    }
}
main
```

```sh
$ ./example.tcl < input.csv
Sox17,Sox8  K562,TCF7L2 CTCF
.   .   .
TCF11   .   .
.   .   MAFF
```

Comment: Hi @Shawn, thanks for your answer. I am getting error:
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
 LANGUAGE = (unset),
 LC_ALL = (unset),
 LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
 LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
"uniq" is not exported by the List::Util module
Can't continue after import errors at -e line 0.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

Comment: @austin7923 You must have an old and/or broken perl installation. Anyways, see updated version.

Comment: Hi @Shawn. The TCL version works flawlessly! Thanks!